# In MongoDB, how do I keep a refference to another collection's _id values?

Tags: mongodb

Basically I have two collections. Buildings and Blueprints.
Buildings have the structure:

{_id:ObjectID("blabla"), blueprint: ObjectID("tralala" )}

Blueprints have a structure

```
{_id:ObjectID("tralala" ) }
```

I simplified them.

Now, how should I keep the blueprint field from Buildings? I thought of keeping them in the "tralala" format as opposed to ObjectID( "tralala" ) because I send these values to my client and I don't want to serialize and deserialze them. If I keep them as "tralala" its just a string which isn't a problem.

But Why would they make it ObjectID if it wasn't important?

How is it best to store a reference to the Blueprint collections?

```
{_id:ObjectID("blabla"), blueprint: ObjectID("tralala" )}
or
{_id:ObjectID("blabla"), blueprint: "tralala"}
```

Related to this, would keeping them as ObjectID help with indexing or whatnot?

Comment: What do you mean by: `ObjectID("tralala")`? An `ObjectID` is by definition a 12 byte number. Keeping a document's ID an `ObjectID` isn't important -- it will be indexed regardless and **must** be unique within a collection.

Comment: The hex nr and its string representation is not the point of my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of your question is. Store the `_id` of one document in the other document, just like a foreign key: `blueprint_id`.

Comment: "they" didn't make it ObjectId - you did when you didn't provide a different - more meaningful natural primary key.  It always better to store the reference as something meaningful (as long as it's unique) so "username" instead of ObjectId() of user collection - for you I don't know what it would be - presumably you do since you designed the schema?

Comment: My problem is that I am sending this data to my client and the _id is turned to string. When the client then sends that value back inside the whole collection json, its still a string rather than ObjectID( that string) and the query fails because valueString != ObjectID( valueString ). I then have to perform additional operations to for _id as String to _id as ObjectID to then make the query... Is it clearer now, WiredPrairie?